# Xml file to database using wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

In the first step we will create a table in SQL Server; after that we create a simple function to insert data into the database using a WCF service. In a web application, add a reference of the service and data to be inserted will be sent to the web services function which will be inserted into the database tableIservice.cs

```
 public interface IService1  
{  
[OperationContract]  
string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo);  
}
```

Now add types to service operations in the DataContract section:

```
public class UserDetails  
{  
string username = string.Empty;  
string password = string.Empty;  
string country = string.Empty;  
string email = string.Empty;  
[DataMember]  
public string UserName  
{  
    get { return username; }  
    set { username = value; }  
}  
[DataMember]  
public string Password  
{  
    get { return password; }  
    set { password = value; }  
}  
[DataMember]  
public string Country  
{  
    get { return country; }  
    set { country = value; }  
}  
[DataMember]  
public string Email  
{  
    get { return email; }  
    set { email = value; }  
}  
}  



 using System;  
 using System.Collections.Generic;  
 using System.Linq;  
 using System.Runtime.Serialization;  
 using System.ServiceModel;  
 using System.ServiceModel.Web;  
 using System.Text;  
 using System.Data.SqlClient;  
 using System.Data;  
  namespace WCFServiceForInsert  
{  
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.  
public class Service1 : IService1  
{  
    public string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)  
    {  
        string Message;  
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Rajesh;User ID=sa;Password=wintellect");  
        con.Open();  
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into RegistrationTable(UserName,Password,Country,Email) values(@UserName,@Password,@Country,@Email)", con);  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userInfo.UserName);  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", userInfo.Password);  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", userInfo.Country);  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", userInfo.Email);  
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
        if (result == 1)  
        {  
            Message = userInfo.UserName + " Details inserted successfully";  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            Message = userInfo.UserName + " Details not inserted successfully";  
        }  
        con.Close();  
        return Message;  
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a concrete question or detailed error.

Comment: What's the question? Side notes: Do not hard code the connection string, store it in a settings file. Do not use `AddWithValule` instead specify `SqlDbType` and length/precision for each parameter. Do not store plain-text passwords, salt and hash them instead. Use `using` to ensure the connection is closed, even if there is an exception. Do not block with a message box while the connection is open. `if (result == 1)` is a waste of time: if the insert didn't happen you would have had an exception, use `try` `catch` instead

Comment: You probably want to remove your DB's sa password from the internet.  Your code looks reasonable, so the problem must be somewhere else. Could you tell us what is going wrong? error messages? Missing data?

Comment: Is there a problem connecting to the database or is it not running successfully? Please provide some specific errors or logs.

Comment: I need to insert xml data into database using wcf